# Angular 2 RadioButton Checked

Tags: javascript, angular

With the old forms I could set checked the radio button like this:

```
<div class="radio" *ngFor="let transport of transports">
  <label>
   <input type="radio" name="transport" [ngModel]="{checked: transport.id == selectedTransport.id}" (change)="onTransportChange(transport)"> {{ transport.name }}
  </label>
</div>
```

With the new angular forms I couldn't achieve this with `[ngModel]="{checked:''}"`, but I can use `[checked]`, then I tried to do:

```
<input type="radio" name="transport" [checked]="transport.id == selectedTransport.id"> {{ transport.name }}
```

And this works, but if I set `[ngModel]` this doesn't check anymore:

```
<input type="radio" name="transport" [checked]="transport.id == selectedTransport.id" [ngModel]="transport" (change)="onTransportChange(transport)"> {{ transport.name }}
```

**Edit:**

Plunker with old forms:
http://plnkr.co/edit/zu4j9MpALIgCT9JHuIPz?p=preview

Plunker with new forms:
http://plnkr.co/edit/cWCp5d122h3wvSRa8AYQ?p=preview

Anyone can help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: What value does your ng-model returning..?? Its value might be causing the radio button unchecked again...

Comment: @Mr.Noddy thanks for the reply, I edited my question, added a plunker with old and new forms...

Comment: Did you find a solution in the meantime?

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify value attributes. 
And do not forget that in case of radio buttons Model is not supposed to contain boolean value but should contain radio specific values like:

> ```
>   <input type="radio" name="food" value="beef" [(ngModel)]="myFood"> Beef
>   <input type="radio" name="food" value="lamb" [(ngModel)]="myFood"> Lamb
>   <input type="radio" name="food" value="fish" [(ngModel)]="myFood"> Fish
> ```

In this case you do not need [checked] attribute.